# ng-repeat not updating the view on updation of array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying a list of host in the table under "hostController" controller. ClusterController is parent of hostController. Host is a tab inside Cluster view. Call for getting host should be done only when the cluster list is available(which is called when the dropdown on cluster view is clicked). So even if we have selected host tab, the host list call should not be fired and hence the host list should not be displayed(as cluster list is not available). But if we have selected host tab, and then we clicked the dropdown of cluster view to get the cluster list, the host list should be displayed. But its not happening so. The host list gets updated but the same changes is not displayed in the UI.

The dropdown in Cluster view which will call getClusterList() and will update the showNavContent poperty. The host list should be displayed only when showNavContent property is true. I am compiling the hostController again inside the clusterController, so the function getHostList is called and updated the hostVm.hostList property but on the UI it is not reflected.

```
//ClusterController

function clusterController($scope, $controller, $rootScope) {

    var vm = this,
        hostVm;

    $rootScope.showNavContent = false;

    function getClusterList() {
        clusterStore.getClusterList().then(function(data) {

            $rootScope.showNavContent = true;
            hostVm = $controller("hostController as hostVm", { $scope: $scope});                
        });
    };


//HostController 

app.controller("hostController", hostController);

  function hostController($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, hostStore, tabManager) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.getHostList = getHostList;
    vm.activeTab = tabManager.getActiveTab();
    vm.hostList = [];

    init();

    function getHostList() {
        hostStore.getHostList().then(function(data) {
            vm.hostList = data.data;

            console.log(vm.hostList);
        });
    }

    function init() {
        if($rootScope.showNavContent === true) {
            vm.getHostList();
        }            
    }
}

 //host.html
 <div class="flex-table">
        <div class="ft-row" ng-repeat="host in hostVm.hostList">
            <div class="ft-column">
                <div class="host-name">{{host.name}}</div>
                <div>{{host.ip}}</div>
            </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating the hostController manually? Why don't you just apply it to the html directly using ng-controller?

Comment: @Chanthu I have done that using $stateProvider. I have called it again inside clusterController so that the function getHostList should be called again as this function is on the hostController's instance.

Comment: Ok so it's really hard trying to see exactly what's wrong just by looking at bits and pieces of code. How about a quick plunkr?